# Trying to return 1 field from lookup of another using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have the following express route and I am trying to return the value of a specific field in my user model by looking up the user email. Even running the following where I am not limiting to a specific field is generating an error:

```
"message": "Cast to string failed for value \"[object Object]\" at path \"email\"",
```

My code:

```
app.post('/users/forgot',(req, res) => {
var body =  _.pick(req.body, ['email']);
    User.find({
        email: body
    }).then((user) => {
        res.send({user});
    }, (e) => {
        res.status(400).send(e);
    });
});
```

How can I return the value I am looking for?

Comment: `body` is an object, not a string. You can try to log it before you do the query.

Comment: Could you print in console what is the value of body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#pick), _.pick returns the object containing the selected value. So, in the following line, `body` is `object`, not `string`

```
var body =  _.pick(req.body, ['email']); // {'email' : 'some@some.com'}
```

Try

```
app.post('/users/forgot',(req, res) => {
  var body =  req.body.email; // or  _.get(body, 'email')
  User.find({
    email: body
  }).then((user) => {
    res.send({user});
  }, (e) => {
    res.status(400).send(e);
  });
});
```

Comment: That solved my initial problem so I am marking as done.- secondary problem is that i have a model method that only allows returning of certain fields - in this particular instance I need to return a field not in that list. Is there a way to override the model method and return another field?